# Task Scheduler action on drive mount

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a drive that uses TrueCrypt. I have a program installed that uses that drive. If I start the program and the TrueCrypt drive hasn't been mounted, it gets very upset. So, I would like to have a task in the Task Scheduler that starts the program when the drive becomes accessible.

How would I set up the trigger for such a task? Perhaps the trigger would be something like "as soon as D:\ becomes available" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using WMI. Here's a quick and dirty example taken from here: [WMI Tasks: Disks and File Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
   & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService. _
   ExecNotificationQuery( _
     "Select * from Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
   Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
   If objLatestEvent.DriveName = "F:" Then
      objShell.Run("""%windir%\system32\notepad.exe""")     
   End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always write up a [batch script](http://www.forwestmedia.com/resources/how-to-guides/truecrypt-using-batch-scripts-to-mount-and-dismount-volumes) to mount the drive, start the program you want, and dismount on close, and use a shortcut in place of all shortcuts for the shortcuts for the program you have installed that uses that drive.

Comment: This was definitely the simplest way to do it, thanks for the suggestion. This is what I went with, but doesn't specifically address the question so I accepted the other one.

Comment: I'm just glad you found a good solution :-)